# Spring MongoDB and GraphQL

Tags: spring, mongodb, graphql

We want to try GraphQL in our Spring based application. (its not based on spring boot). Our data repository is MongoDB.  I saw various examples based on node, which makes use of graphQL + Mongo.  There is also library which is with spring boot! 
Can it be used directly? Or there is non spring-boot lib available?

Comment: If it is not Spring boot based project then you cannot use spring boot dependency directly. If you want to use the library then you will have to update the project to spring boot project [Create example project to view the structure and pom file](https://start.spring.io/). If in case you use [graphql-spring-boot-starter](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql) then it will already provide you quite many features just by adding the dependency. If you are not migrating the project to spring boot type then I would advise you to try examples which you have already seen.

Comment: @Neelesh thanks.. even i was trying to cut portion .. we have one big giant project and very hard to upgrade to boot.. still team is trying.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you'd gain from Spring Boot is auto configuration for Spring Data's Mongo driver.

If you're comfortable injecting the MongoRepository into the GraphQL data sources and resolves on your own, then no, you don't need Spring Boot